# Populate a table by using Single pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, jtable, singleton

I have created following singleton design pattern in my java program

```
      private int OwnerId;
    private String OwnerName;
    private String OwnerNic;
    private String OwnerAddress;
    private int OwnerTele;
    private String OwnerEmail;
    private String OwnerDate;


   private static OwnerML instance = new OwnerML();


    // make the coosntructor private so that this class cannot be instantiated
    private OwnerML(){}
     // get the only object available

   public static OwnerML getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }



    public int getOwnerId() {
        return OwnerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(int OwnerId) {
        this.OwnerId = OwnerId;
    }
```

I have used a separate method to call the view method

```
   public ArrayList<OwnerML> SelectOwnerData()
{

    ArrayList<OwnerML> OwnerList = new ArrayList<OwnerML>();
   try {
       Connection con = DB.connect();
       String selectQ = "select * from owners";
       PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(selectQ);
       ResultSet rs = ps2.executeQuery();


        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            OwnerML OwnerData =OwnerML.getInstance();
            OwnerData.setOwnerId(rs.getInt(1));
            OwnerData.setOwnerName(rs.getString(2));
            OwnerData.setOwnerNic(rs.getString(3));
            OwnerData.setOwnerAddress(rs.getString(4));
            OwnerData.setOwnerTele(rs.getInt(5));     
            OwnerData.setOwnerEmail(rs.getString(6));  
            OwnerList.add(OwnerData);

        }
        rs.close();
       ps2.close();
       con.close();
```

By using following method I'm calling it in my interface

```
 ArrayList<OwnerML> ownerList = new OwnerCL().SelectOwnerData();

    Object obj[][] = new Object[ownerList.size()][6];
    int x = 0;
    for (OwnerML t : ownerList) {

        obj[x][0] = t.getOwnerId();
        obj[x][1] = t.getOwnerName();
        obj[x][2] = t.getOwnerNic();
        obj[x][3] = t.getOwnerAddress();
        obj[x][4] = t.getOwnerTele();
        obj[x][5] = t.getOwnerEmail();
        x++;
    }
        ownerTbl.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(obj,new Object[]{

        "OwneID", "Name", "Nic", "Address", "Tele", "Email", "Date", "VehicleID", "Type", "Model", "Year", "RegNumber"
    }));
```

The problem I am facing at the moment is that  it always repeats the  data in the last row.
I would be very thankful if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: That is the purpose of the singleton pattern, isn't it - to always have the same instance. When you read the data from the DB you can just create a new object for every record and then show these objects in your table and this way get rid of the singleton pattern (which is also considered an anti-pattern by many).

Answer (score 1):

There is one mayor flaw in your design.
I guess `OwnerML` class is supposed to be the container for the data. It does not make sense to implement it as a Singleton.

Every time you call `OwnerML.getInstance()` while populating the `OwnerList` list with results from the database, you are referencing the same class' instance (it's the very nature of Singleton).
As a result you will always have a list with multiple references to the same object (singleton).

You should forget about using Singleton as a data container (let's call it Data Transfer Object - DTO). 
In fact Singleton is rarely useful for anything (notably exceptions are: logging subsystem, handler of singular hardware resource, and maybe Spring-ish bean factory).

In short: 
make the `OwnerML` constructor public and then replace
`OwnerML OwnerData =OwnerML.getInstance();`
with
`OwnerML OwnerData = new OwnerML();`

===EDIT===

@Anton 's comment was first, and he's right. I should type faster next time :)